# Issues with extended_id and socketcan_native

Tags: python-3.x, can-bus

Good morning, I am using git hub examples as a base to make a can bus connection through the pican2 duo can, the python can configuration and the pican2 drivers were installed correctly the problem comes when running the code since A few seconds after running the program I get the extended_id and socketcan_native error, it appears as follows:
" **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_extended_id'".
I am viewing the comments and it has worked for several of them and several have the same problem. If anyone has the same problem or has already solved it, can you guide me.
I am using python can 4.1.0.

And tried to fix it by downloading older versions of python can, but when entering the commands : sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade automatically upgrades me to the newest version of python. I have to send these commands to be able to use the pican2 duo can card.
I leave the url that I am using
https://github.com/skpang/PiCAN-Python-examples/blob/master/obdii_logger.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#
## obdii_logger.py
# 
# This python3 program sends out OBDII request then logs the reply to the sd card.
# For use with PiCAN boards on the Raspberry Pi
# http://skpang.co.uk/catalog/pican2-canbus-board-for-raspberry-pi-2-p-1475.html
#
# Make sure Python-CAN is installed first http://skpang.co.uk/blog/archives/1220
#
#  24-08-16 SK Pang
#

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import can
import time
import os
import queue
from threading import Thread

led = 22
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(led,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(led,True)

# For a list of PIDs visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs
ENGINE_COOLANT_TEMP = 0x05
ENGINE_RPM          = 0x0C
VEHICLE_SPEED       = 0x0D
MAF_SENSOR          = 0x10
O2_VOLTAGE          = 0x14
THROTTLE            = 0x11

PID_REQUEST         = 0x7DF
PID_REPLY           = 0x7E8

outfile = open('log.txt','w')


print('\n\rCAN Rx test')
print('Bring up CAN0....')

# Bring up can0 interface at 500kbps
os.system("sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000")
time.sleep(0.1) 
print('Ready')

try:
    bus = can.interface.Bus(channel='can0', bustype='socketcan_native')
except OSError:
    print('Cannot find PiCAN board.')
    GPIO.output(led,False)
    exit()

def can_rx_task():  # Receive thread
    while True:
        message = bus.recv()
        if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY:
            q.put(message)          # Put message into queue

def can_tx_task():  # Transmit thread
    while True:

        GPIO.output(led,True)
        # Sent a Engine coolant temperature request
        msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,ENGINE_COOLANT_TEMP,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],extended_id=False)
        bus.send(msg)
        time.sleep(0.05)

        # Sent a Engine RPM request
        msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,ENGINE_RPM,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],extended_id=False)
        bus.send(msg)
        time.sleep(0.05)

        # Sent a Vehicle speed  request
        msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,VEHICLE_SPEED,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],extended_id=False)
        bus.send(msg)
        time.sleep(0.05)        

        # Sent a Throttle position request
        msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,THROTTLE,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],extended_id=False)
        bus.send(msg)
        time.sleep(0.05)
        
        GPIO.output(led,False)
        time.sleep(0.1)
                        
                        
q = queue.Queue()
rx = Thread(target = can_rx_task)  
rx.start()
tx = Thread(target = can_tx_task)
tx.start()

temperature = 0
rpm = 0
speed = 0
throttle = 0
c = ''
count = 0

# Main loop
try:
    while True:
        for i in range(4):
            while(q.empty() == True):   # Wait until there is a message
                pass
            message = q.get()

            c = '{0:f},{1:d},'.format(message.timestamp,count)
            if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == ENGINE_COOLANT_TEMP:
                temperature = message.data[3] - 40          #Convert data into temperature in degree C

            if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == ENGINE_RPM:
                rpm = round(((message.data[3]*256) + message.data[4])/4)    # Convert data to RPM

            if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == VEHICLE_SPEED:
                speed = message.data[3]                                     # Convert data to km

            if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == THROTTLE:
                throttle = round((message.data[3]*100)/255)                 # Conver data to %

        c += '{0:d},{1:d},{2:d},{3:d}'.format(temperature,rpm,speed,throttle)
        print('\r {} '.format(c))
        print(c,file = outfile) # Save data to file
        count += 1
            

 
    
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    #Catch keyboard interrupt
    GPIO.output(led,False)
    outfile.close()     # Close logger file
    os.system("sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 down")
    print('\n\rKeyboard interrtupt')
```

Answer (score 1):

I found through experimentation that changing 'socketcan-native' to 'socketcan' got me past that error.  This worked for me:
bus = can.interface.Bus(channel = 'can0', bustype = 'socketcan')

The can.interface.Bus() call works for me when I use:
message = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x111, data=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], is_extended_id=False)

When I got the sample code it didn't have:
is_exteneded_id
Instead it had:
extended_id
I notice in your code you have:
extended_id

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer has helped me a lot, the errors completely disappeared but now "No buffer space available" appears. I did some research and according to various sources this problem goes away when I run the command "sudo ifconfig can0 txqueuelen 1000", when I run this command the error goes away as it changes its name now shortly after initializing I get the following error "Transmit buffer full". Do you know the reason for this problem?